# Track scroll position according to visible section

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, scroll, match

I am having some trouble tracking the scroll position. I am trying to set a variable according to what section is visible.
My html looks like this

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="main">
    <section id="one"><h2>BLA BLA</h2></section>
    <section id="two"><h2>MJALLO!</h2></section>
    <section id="three"><h2>MJALLO!</h2></section>
    <section id="four"><h2>MJALLO!</h2></section>
    <section id="five"><h2>MJALLO!</h2></section>
   </div>
</body>
```

As said, i am trying to track the $(document) position and match it with a section id. I have for this the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var window = $(window);
var view = "";

 if (window.scrollTop == $("#one").offset().top) 
   {view = "1";}
 else if (window.scrollTop == $("#two").offset().top) 
   {view = "2";}
 else if (window.scrollTop == $("#three").offset().top) 
   {view = "3";}
 else if (window.scrollTop == $("#four").offset().top) 
   {view = "4";}
 else if (window.scrollTop == $("#five").offset().top) 
   {view = "5";}
});
```

The section are styled as full frame blocks but i can't get any reaction on this if statement.

I am new to jQuery and js so a bit explanation would be appreciated ;)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the ifs in a "on scroll" function:

```
$( document ).scroll(function() {
  if(....)
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: It doesn't seems to work :S 
I've tried change the $( document ).ready into $( document ).scroll, and I've tried to wrap the if() else if() statements in a $( document ).scroll as well.. :/ 

But i still don't get any reactions

Comment: It works now.. For some reason, when i added an ekstra = so it was window.scrollTop === $("#one").offset().top), it started to work. With the on scroll wrapper. 
Thanks a lot